# view record using id

Tags: php, sql

i can view the list of the users but when i'm trying to view the user record using their id, the output from the database doesn't show. i have done this before but i didn't have any clue why this time it doesn't work.

user_list.php

```
<?php

    include 'connection.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM formequip, equipment, department WHERE formequip.equip_id = equipment.equip_id = department.depart_id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed. ' . mysql_error());

?>

<div  class="container" style="margin-top: 10px">
     <table width="100%" border="0" class=" table table-striped table-bordered" id="mak_pekerja">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#666666">
                <th width="2%" nowrap="nowrap">Bil</th>
                <th width="2%" nowrap="nowrap">Jabatan</th>
                <th width="14%" nowrap="nowrap">Nama</th>
                <th width="7%" nowrap="nowrap">Kad Matrik</th>
                <th width="9%" nowrap="nowrap">No.Telefon</th>
                <th width="10%" nowrap="nowrap">Tarikh Pinjam</th>
                <th width="12%" nowrap="nowrap">Tarikh Hantar</th>
                <th width="15%" nowrap="nowrap">Aktiviti</th>
                <th width="15%" nowrap="nowrap">Perkara</th>
                <th width="15%" nowrap="nowrap">Kuantiti</th>
                <th width="15%" nowrap="nowrap">Status</th>
                <th width="16%" nowrap="nowrap">Tetapan</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <?php 
                   $tmpCount = 1; 
                       while ($row_lprn = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>        
                    <tr bgcolor="#DDD">
                      <td><?php echo $tmpCount; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row_lprn['department']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row_lprn['stud_name']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row_lprn['stud_id']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row_lprn['stud_tel']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row_lprn['stud_date_borrow']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row_lprn['stud_date_return'];?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row_lprn['stud_activity']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row_lprn['equip_type']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row_lprn['stud_quantity']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row_lprn['stud_status']; ?></td>
                      <td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row_lprn['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger"> <i class="icon-list-alt icon-white"></i>Edit</a></td>
                      <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row_lprn['id']; ?>" /></td>
                    </tr>                        
             <?php $tmpCount ++; }?>                                              
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

update.php

```
 <?php
        include('connection.php');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM formequip WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'";
        $results = mysql_query($sql);

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);

        $id = $row_lprn['id'];
        $stud_id = $row_lprn['stud_id'];
        $equip_id = $row_lprn['equip_type'];
        $stud_name = $row_lprn['stud_name'];
        $stud_tel = $row_lprn['stud_tel'];
        $stud_activity = $row_lprn['stud_activity'];
        $stud_date_borrow = $row_lprn['stud_date_borrow'];
        $stud_date_return = $row_lprn['stud_date_return'];
        $equip_type = $row_lprn['equip_type'];
        $stud_quantity = $row_lprn['stud_quantity'];

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $submit = $_POST['submit'];

        ?>

<p>
        <div id="form">
        <form name="update" action="update2.php" method="post">
            <table width="800" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>No. ID</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><?php echo "$id"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>No. Matrik</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><?php echo "$stud_id"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="173">Jabatan</td>
                    <td width="10">:</td>
                    <td width="564"><?php echo "$department"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nama Pemohon</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><?php echo "$stud_name"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>No. Telefon</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><?php echo "$stud_tel"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Aktiviti</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><?php echo "$stud_activity"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tarikh Pinjam</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><?php echo "$stud_date_borrow"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tarikh Pulang</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><?php echo "$stud_date_return"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Perkara</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><?php echo "$equip_type"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Kuantiti</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><?php echo "$stud_quantity"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Status</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><label>
                        <select name="stud_status" id="stud_status">
                        <option selected="selected"></option>
                        <option>Diluluskan</option>
                        <option>Tidak Diluluskan</option>
                        </select>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <p align="center">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="stud_name" value="<?php echo $stud_name; ?>">

                </p>
            </table><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Kemaskini" />
        </form><form action="user_list.php">
    <input type="submit" value="kembali"></form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the output will be displayed like this:

[image]

thank you for your help :)

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Comment: Show the `form` in your `user_list.php` file where `id` is set. I don't see how `$_POST['id']` gets set properly in your `update.php` script. I see a `hidden` input, but not the enclosing `form` element.

Comment: Yes, in the example, you're sending the id via GET not POST. Your hidden field does nothing without a form, as @RyanJ stated.

Comment: In fact, since you have the 'Edit' link in a column, the hidden field seems unnecessary. You just need to change update.php to fetch $_GET['id'], but filter it with filter_var() before, per example.

Comment: Ahh, there's how it's being set. I didn't see the `href` setting a variable for the id. Yes, use the `$_GET` array to get your id, not `$_POST`, and make sure to check user input by filtering/escaping for security reasons.

Comment: i'm still confused. I change it to GET but the only one that shows are the 'ID' field. others are still empty

Answer (score 1):

You realy wanna make this query?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM formequip, equipment, department WHERE formequip.equip_id = equipment.equip_id = department.depart_id";
```

You are comparing equip_id from two tables, with depart_id from a third table.

Next, you called **"formequip.equip_id"** at the first file, and **formequip.id** at the second.

I think your problem should be solved by using this line:
Edit: Use $_GET instead of $_POST

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM formequip WHERE equip_id=".$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: yes. i can view the list of the user (name, telephone, activity,department ect) base on the three tables. the update.php doesn't display the view though..

Answer (score 0):

How did you declare Id in the database? if it is an integer, you have to remove the apostrophes from the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM formequip WHERE id=".$_POST['id'];
```

Regards.

Comment: are you sure its written like that?